# Specify multiple conditions in long form data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

How do I index rows I need by with specifications?

```
id<-c(65,65,65,65,65,900,900,900,900,900,900,211,211,211,211,211,211,211,45,45,45,45,45,45,45)
age<-c(19,22,23,24,25,21,26,31,32,37,38,22,23,25,28,29,31,32,30,31,36,39,42,44,48)
stat<-c('intern','reg','manage1','left','reg','manage1','manage2','left','reg',
        'reg','left','intern','left','intern','reg','left','reg','manage1','reg','left','intern','manage1','left','reg','manage2')

mydf<-data.frame(id,age,stat)
```

I need to create 5 variables:

1. m01time & m12time: measure the amount of years elapsed before becoming a level1 manager (manage1), and then since manage1 to manage2 regardless of whether or not it's at the same job. (numeric in years)
2. change: capture whether or not they experienced a job change between manage1 and manage2 (if 'left' happens somewhere in between manage1 and manage2), (0 or 1)
3. & 4: m1p & m2p: capture the position before becoming manager1 and manager2 (intern, reg, or manage1).

There's a lot of information I don't need here that I am not sure how to ignore (all the jobs 211 went through before going to one where they become a manager).

The end result should look something like this:

```
   id m01time m02time change    m1p     m2p
1  65       4      NA     NA    reg    <NA>
2 900      NA       5      0   <NA> manage1
3 211       1      NA     NA    reg    <NA>
4  45       3       9      1 intern     reg
```

I tried to use ifelse with lag() and lead() to capture some conditions, but there are more for loop type of jobs (such as how to capture a "left" somewhere in between) that I am not sure what to do with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd calculate the variables the first three variables differently than `m1p` and `m2p`. Maybe there's an elegant unified approach that I don't see at the moment.

So for the last position before manager you could do:

```
mydt <- data.table(mydf)
mydt[,.(m1p=stat[.I[stat=="manage1"]-1],
        m2p=stat[.I[stat=="manage2"]-1]),by=id]
```

The other variables are more conveniently calculated in a wide data.format:

```
dt <- dcast(unique(mydt,by=c("id","stat")), 
           formula=id~stat,value.var="age")
dt[,.(m01time = manage1-intern,
      m12time = manage2-manage1,
      change  = manage1<left & left<manage2)]
```

Two caveats:

- reshaping might be quite costly larger data sets
- I (over-)simplified your dummy data by ignoring duplicates of `id` and `stat`